# Can I make VueI18n fallback on a key path if not found the complete key path?

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

Is it possible for `VueI18n` to fall back to shorter key if it didn't found it.

A example for this could be, I have following messages:

```
{
   en: {
      "hello": "This is the fallback message!",
      "admin.hello": "This is some other message for another context"
   }
}
```

The below code is a illustration of what the results should be:

```
{{ $t("does.not.exists.hello") }} // should fallback on hello, so the result will be "This is the fallback message!"
{{ $t("admin.hello") }} // Message exists so the result should be "This is some other message for another context"

{{ $t("hello") }} // Message exists so the result should be "This is the fallback message!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I was to fast, with this question. MissingHandler is useful for this.

and the code example became like this:
Vue.use(VueI18n)

// Create VueI18n instance with options

```
export default new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en', // set locale
    silentTranslationWarn: true,
    missing: (locale: Locale, key: Path, vm?: Vue) => {
        if(key.includes(".")) {
            let newKey = /\.(.+)/.exec(key)[1];
            console.log(newKey)
            return vm.$t(newKey) as string
        }
        return key
    },
    //formatter: new CustomFormatter(),
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages // set locale messages
})
```