# Vue.js - Error with vuei18n when trying to translate in the missing handler

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vue-i18n

I try to translate a key through the MissingHandler with vuei18n, but I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNjq7.png): `vm.$t is not a function`. My goal is to ensure that a key is replaced, with a parent key, if it is not found.

I use the following code described here: [Can I make VueI18n fallback on a key path if not found the complete key path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53980799/17703044)

```
export const i18n = createI18n({
  messages,
  legacy: false,
  locale: 'en',
  missing: (locale: Locale, key: Path, vm: Vue, values) => {
    if (key.includes('.')) {
      const newKey = /\.(.+)/.exec(key)[1]
      return vm.$t(newKey) as string
    }
    return key
  },
})

export const install: UserModule = ({ app }) => {
  app.use(i18n)
}
```

I use Vue 3 and the Composition API.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Resolved here : https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next/issues/890